# UITableView reloads data while scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, mkmapview

I've create an app that uses some maps functionality. I've added an MKMapView to the UITableViewCell and WebView to another uiTableviewcell (I need this, because it look elegant). I've created my custom cells.
My uitableview delegate and datasource methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
    switch (section)
    {
        case 0:
            return [self cellForMapView];
        case 1:
            return [self cellForUIWebView];
    }
    return nil;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)cellForMapView
{
    //if (_mapViewCell)
       // return _mapViewCell;

    // if not cached, setup the map view...
    CGFloat cellWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width - 20;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        cellWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width - 90;
    }

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cellWidth, 241);
    _mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    _mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    _mapView.userLocation.title = @"Текущее местоположение";
    _mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    _mapView.zoomEnabled = YES;

    NSString * cellID = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellID] autorelease];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_mapView];

    _mapViewCell = cell;

    return cell;
}



/*
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 return 50.0f;
 } */

-(UITableViewCell *)cellForUIWebView
{
    //if (_webViewCell)
       // return _webViewCell;

    CGFloat cellWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width - 20 ;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        cellWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width - 90;
    }

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cellWidth, 241);
    _webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    NSString * cellID = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellID]autorelease];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:_webView];

    _webViewCell = cell;
    return cell;
}
```

I'm downloading some data to the webview and to display some annotations on the map. The problem is that when the user is changing orientation and scrolling the tableview data, table view reloads the data automatically (I have my webview and Map being recreated and displaying nothing). How to fix this problem? Maybe I can save the tableviewcell's state?? But how to do it?

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you are trying to store data in your table view cells, but these are managed by the table view. They are not only reloaded as required, but also re-used when they disappear from the screen.
The solution is that you have to store the data in your data model, an object that is independent from the table view. The table view then only loads data from your model for display.

Comment: This times 1000. If I could up vote this five times I would. All the time people are storing data in the view. Not good.

Answer (score 1):

put this condition at the time of allocation of cell

```
if ( ! cell ) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellID]autorelease];
}
```

table view reloads the data automatically because when u scrolls it deallocates cell